# I want to write a trigger, to prevent creation of record, 7 days from the custom date field

Tags: trigger

I have a custom object TIMESHEET__c, which has a custom date field Start_date__c. I don't want any records to be created, which has a  date value within 7 days, or the same date of the existing  Start_date__c.

I have tried writing a trigger:

```
trigger RecordDuplicateTrigger on TIMESHEET__c (before insert) {
       for(TIMESHEET__c a:Trigger.new)
        {
         string uid = userinfo.getName();
          List<TIMESHEET__c> acc=[select Id, CreatedDate, Owner.Name, Start_date__c from TIMESHEET__c where (Owner.Name = :uid AND CreatedDate = THISWEEK)];
              if(acc.size()>0)
              {
                a.adderror('One record is already created for the Day For ' + uid);
              }
        }
    }
```

But this trigger is preventing the creation of records only on the basis of the created date and not the Start Date.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition in your query be where `Start_Date__c = THIS_WEEK` instead of `CreatedDate=THIS_WEEK `. This will prevent a user to create another record this week (not past 7 days).

Comment: Thanks @manjit5190. Even if I am using Start_Date__c = THIS_WEEK, I am unable to create two records on the same day, with a difference of more than 7 days, between the Start date.

Comment: Then it is likely that there are already records which satisfy error conditions. You should run this query and check how many record you are getting. It should be zero. 
`select Id, CreatedDate, Owner.Name, Start_date__c from TIMESHEET__c where (Owner.Name = : <TYPE THE NAME OF THE USER HERE> AND Start_Date__c= THIS_WEEK)`

Answer (score 2):

There's a few flaws in your code:

1. Using a before trigger is the right approach, but you can't and don't need to retrieve the records using SOQL (and definitely not inside a query). Records coming into a before trigger still haven't been committed to the database, and are still editable and for this use case, still preventable for inserting.
2. If we want to retrieve only time sheets owned by the current running user, need to compare vs. the user ID and not the user name. Names can be duplicates, IDs can't.
3. Need to filter by the custom Start Date field, and not the Created Date.

```
    trigger RecordDuplicateTrigger on TIMESHEET__c (before insert) {
      for(TIMESHEET__c ts : Trigger.new){
        if (ts.OwnerId == UserInfo.getUserId()) && (ts.Start_Date__c >= 
          Date.today().addDays(-7)){
           ts.addError('One record is already created for the Day For '+UserInfo.getName())
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help @DavidReed and EranV There seems to be some syntax error in the above-mentioned trigger. I am not able to fix the error. It would be helpful if anyone can fix it. Thanks in advance.